# Why can't I tune the radio to the Poké Flute station?

Tags: pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

I am standing next to the sleeping Snorlax near Vermilion City.

I have completed the power plant quest and I have the radio extension in my Pokégear.

In order to awaken the Snorlax I am trying to tune my Pokégear to the Poké Flute station as I have seen it done in several videos and tutorials online. However, I have looked through all the frequencies and I can not find it. On the frequency that the tutorials show, I get no radio station at all.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you need to talk to the [director in the first floor of the Kanto Radio Tower](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/ds/960099-pokemon-heartgold-version/answers/177218-what-day-is-the-poke-flute-music-on-on-the-radio)

That should get you access to the station since you've already dealt with the power plant.